# airflow triggers DAG, but always redirects to 404

Tags: python, airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image]

airflow triggers DAG, but always redirects to 404.
Triggering DAGs manually with or without config works, but I always get directed to a pointless error page. How can I avoid this? I run airflow in a conda environment with mariadb backend.

anaconda_version: "Anaconda3-2022.11"
python version: 3.7
airflow version: 2.5.3

The scheduler does not show errors.

Help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

I tried restarting airflow and the scheduler, but I have no idea what the issue could be, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the original URL and the URL which you are redirected to?